# How to change logging level without closing a process in C++

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am writing a program which uses boost library for logging

```
    boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
    boost::log::keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%",
    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
    );

    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(
    boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::info
    );
```

I can change the logging level by changing argument in set_filter but is there anyway to change logging level without changing the source code and restarting the process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your application does provide some way of communicating the desired severity level in run time, you can always set a new filter with the new level. Just call `set_filter` whenever you need to update.

```
void update_severity_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity_level new_level)
{
    boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(
        boost::log::trivial::severity >= new_level
    );
}
```

There are also other ways described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049633/setting-boostlog-severity-filter-to-call-a-function-as-opposed-to-using-a-con/35061963#35061963) answer.